# NSTokenField suggestion is slow:what is the process?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autocomplete, nstokenfield

`NSTokenField` takes quite a time to propose suggestion to the text I enter. 
More precisely, here is what happens:

1. I type the letter "a"
2. the method `textDidBeginEditing:` of `NSTokenField` is called immediately
3. some time (approx. 1/2 to 1 second)
4. the method `tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:` is called and its execution is very quick.

I would like to understand what happens and possibly improve this situation.

My question:

**What does happen between `textDidBeginEditing:` and `tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:`?**

---

EDIT

Very strange: if I type ";" instead of "a", it goes much quicker! *even though* I did the following:

```
- (NSArray *)        tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
        completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring
                   indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex
            indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex
{
    return @[@"Hello"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a bug of `OSX 10.9`.

Here is what I did.
The screen:

[image]

(the `textField` is a `NSTokenField`)

Then, in a delegate for this `NSTokenField`, put the following code

```
- (NSArray *)        tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
        completionsForSubstring:(NSString *)substring
                   indexOfToken:(NSInteger)tokenIndex
            indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)selectedIndex
{
    return @[@"Jojo!!"];
}



- (id)                        tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
       representedObjectForEditingString:(NSString *)editingString
{
    return @"Jojo the cat" ;
}




- (NSString *)              tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
     displayStringForRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    return @"Jojo" ;
}
```

You'll see, it bugs.